# Suppose that $a$ has order $15$. Find all of the left cosets of $\langle a^5\rangle$ in $\langle a\rangle$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that $a$ has order $15$.  Find all of the left cosets of $\langle a^5\rangle $ in $\langle a\rangle$ .

Ok, so I know by Lagrange's Theorem, that the order of the subgroup divides the order of the group.  Therefore, the index of the cosets must be $3$.

However...  How do I apply this index to the subgroups?  I know the final answer, I just want the breakdown, in a meaningful way. The text I use did not really elaborate on this with the notation given.  I think I may just be confused for that reason.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: I think you are overlooking a fact that $\langle a \rangle $ is cyclic and therefore abelian.  Thus every subgroup is *normal*.

Comment: Patrick Stevens - I don't know what you're talking about.  The question has been posed on this forum exactly as it was posed to me.   There's no issue with what's displayed.

Comment: hardmath - I understand that point, but how do we apply the index to identifying the elements of the subgroups?

Comment: @Mhan7: There's a clear difference; see the [history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2789018/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If the order of an element $a$ is $n$, the order of $a^k$ is $\;\dfrac n{\gcd(k,n)}$.

*Some explicit details*:

The cosets are :
\begin{align}
&\langle\mkern2mu a^5\mkern1mu\rangle=\{\, 1,a^5, a^{10}\,\},&&a\,\langle\mkern2mu a^5\mkern1mu\rangle=\{\, a,a^6, a^{11}\,\},&&a^2\langle\mkern2mu a^5\mkern1mu\rangle=\{\, a^2,a^7, a^{12}\,\},\\[1ex]
&a^3\langle\mkern2mu a^5\mkern1mu\rangle=\{\, a^3,a^8, a^{13}\,\}, 
&&a^4\langle\mkern2mu a^5\mkern1mu\rangle=\{\, a^4,a^9, a^{14}\,\}.
\end{align}

Comment: But I'm not looking for order, am I?  I'm looking for all of the elements of the left cosets.

Comment: The number of left cosets is the number of elements of the quotient. Then you can use *Lagrange's theorem*.

Comment: Right, but once I have that "index", now what?  I know there are 5 left cosets, and that there are 3 elements in each coset.  Now...  about those 3 elements in the index?  They are generators for the remainders of the cosets.  Please explain...

Comment: Clearly the cosets are $\{\,a^i\langle a^5\rangle,\;0\le i\le4\,\}$ . What else do you want to know?

Comment: why is that clear?  (other than everything is easy, when you know how it's done)   The inequality doesn't really satisfy the index values.  What are the values, specifically?  I know what's given, but not how they were obtained.

Comment: Because the hint implies that any two powers $a^i$ with exponent differing by a multiple of $5$ generate the same coset.

Comment: Not to be dense...  But I'm not following that.  Please don't misunderstand my intent.  I have the final answer(s).  I'm only trying to understand the step that was used in multiplying $a^i$ times the 3 items that constitute $a^5 $ . (what those items actually were)  I feel like I'm missing something really elementary.

Comment: You multiply by the three items in the subgroup because it is the mere definition of a coset. Is that a difficulty?

Comment: *sigh* - I'm trying to tell you that I don't know what those 3 items are.  As in, what their actual values are...  How do I determine the values?  I just don't know how to ask this question any clearer...

Comment: The three items are just the elements of the subgroup generated by $a^5$. What else can I say?

Comment: Maybe what they are, and how you obtained them...

Comment: I just noticed that you edited the post above, and showed the cosets. My issue was how you obtained the values of $<a^5>$ .  From what I see, the values would be {0, 1, 2}.  But why?  Every other coset will be multiplied by this value, so I'm looking for the explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. The values of $\langle a^5\rangle$ are just the *distinct* powers of $a^5$. As soon as you obtain a multiple of $15$, the power of $a^5$ is equal to $1$, so we're back at the starting point. Maybe an arithmetic explanation will be more illuminating: $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}$ is the least integer $\ell$ such that $\ell\, k=\operatorname{lcm}(n,k)$.